# Trying to use Select tag and Onchange for custom ordered list

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

I'm very new to Javascript and functions...I've tried to go as far as I can this, but I'm at a dead end.  What I'm trying to do is allow users to use drop-down boxes to manually change the sort order of a dataset.  As an example, using the following data:

```
Name    SortOrder
Bob     1
John    2
Mary    3
Susan   4
Frank   5
Allison 6
Katie   7
Scott   8
```

Let's say the user wants to display John at the top of the list and Susan as the second on the list.  When the user changes John's SortOrder to 1, I want Bob's SortOrder to change to 2.  When Susan's is changed to 2, I want Bob's to then change to 3 and Mary's to change to 4.  I'm *so* close on this, but the list doesn't cooperate once a change or two have been made.  Here is my function:

```
<script>
function changeField(newval, oldval, maxfield, fieldid) {
var val = newval.value;
var oldval = Number(oldval);
var maxfield = Number(maxfield);
for (var i = 1; i <= maxfield; i++) {
    var curval = Number(document.getElementById("sortorder" + i).value);
    if (val < oldval) {
        if (curval >= val && curval < oldval && fieldid != "sortorder" + i) {
            document.getElementById("sortorder" + i).value = curval + 1;
            }
        }
    if (val > oldval) {
        if (curval <= val && curval > oldval && fieldid != "sortorder" + i) {
            document.getElementById("sortorder" + i).value = curval - 1;
            }
        }
    }

for (var n = 1; n <= maxfield; n++) {
    var newfieldid= "sortorder" + document.getElementById("sortorder" + n).value;
    document.getElementById("sortorder" + n).id = newfieldid;
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is the select box:

```
echo '<select id="sortorder' . $crow['catSortOrder'] . '" onchange="changeField(this, ' . $crow['catSortOrder'] . ', ' . $numcat . ', \'sortorder' . $crow['catSortOrder'] . '\');">';
for ($v=1; $v<=$numcat; $v++) {
echo '<option id="optid" value=' . $v . ($v == $crow['catSortOrder'] ? " selected = \"yes\"" : "") . '>' . $v . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

The $crow['catSortOrder'] brings in the value from the SortOrder field (Bob = 1, John = 2, etc).  $numcat is the number of rows in the list (in my example, 4).  So what I'm passing in the function call is the new value (after the field has been changed), the old value, the maximum number, and the select field id (sortorder1, sortorder2, etc).

The intent of the function is to change any applicable values between the old value and the new value.  As I stated before, if John is changed to 1, Bob's select option changes to 2.  If I move Susan up to 2, Bob then moves to 3 and Mary then moves to 4.

The last part of the function (for n) is meant to assign a new value to the id tag of the select boxes after a change has been made.  So when John's value is changed to 1 and Bob's in turn changed to 2, the ids then update to sortorder1 and sortorder2, respectively.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  I feel like I'm so close but can't quite close this out!

Answer (score 0):

One error is how you are getting the value of a select. Here is the correct way.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/2635438

I corrected the first occurrence of getting value of select here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/DWDJp/

```
function changeField(newval, oldval, maxfield, fieldid) {
    var val = newval.value;
    var oldval = Number(oldval);
    var maxfield = Number(maxfield);
    for (var i = 1; i <= maxfield; i++) {
        // var curval = Number(document.getElementById("sortorder" + i).value);
        var e = document.getElementById("sortorder" + i);
        var curval = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (val < oldval) {
            if (curval >= val && curval < oldval && fieldid != "sortorder" + i) {
                document.getElementById("sortorder" + i).value = curval + 1;
            }
        }
        if (val > oldval) {
            if (curval <= val && curval > oldval && fieldid != "sortorder" + i) {
                document.getElementById("sortorder" + i).value = curval - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var n = 1; n <= maxfield; n++) {
        var newfieldid = "sortorder" + document.getElementById("sortorder" + n).value;
        document.getElementById("sortorder" + n).id = newfieldid;
    }
}
```

First change works but throws error after that. 
Use your developer tools in your browser to see javascript errors.